# Azure AD automatically added offline_access

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

For Microsoft [OAuth 2.0 auth code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code), we have encountered an issue with scopes.

When we requestion *only* the `User.Read` scope, our client is asked to grant permission to us for **Sign you in and read your profile** and **Access your data anytime**. Where we didn't state we need `offline_access` scope.

[image]

This is only happening after Microsoft switched to new permission grant interface. Have someone else encounter the same issue or we did something wrong?

The `response_type` we pass in is `code` only.

[image]

I have double checked, the application we registered is under `https://apps.dev.microsoft.com`.

The URL we use for authorizing is following.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
```

As I said earlier, the only scope we pass in through query was `User.Read`.

**Edit 3**

Request URL: (*I have removed client id.*)

`https://login.microsoftonline.com:443/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A19974%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fmicrosoft%2Foauth2%2Fsession&response_mode=form_post&scope=User.Read&state=1527572151-IIZ0D&nonce=1527572151-IIZ0D&prompt=consent&domain_hint=organizations`

Response that logged with fiddler:

---

POST http://localhost:19974/api/v1/microsoft/oauth2/session HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:19974
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 798
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: null
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,en-NZ;q=0.9,zh-TW;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.6
DNT: 1

code=OAQABAAIAAADX8GCi6Js6SK82TsD2Pb7rUmGhJoHUB3devvTffqTlhRhg9XZ202zgEA8B37CzgkeLNVBc4FFstw3sTjNmYhKCYLE_jcl7KeCrtYgPVFYOKUuazv_B3vHKIM8ttwIzOlV_3GL4vqxPgjvXbWUdas5Sj9Z1X9fEBB63Wa1Ig0AnisnHk6qagIimFEPApYx473RzgIve2erM3r5fnX5Q0L1-pHppSFUJoWop6MPTkUh-umPzuXQgB280rHyUds3odS6_cJP6SbI70aLNOqHV_AnaV_VUZqQ6hLfBZMVKFMYMg_r_harPOU5EE2gf2d15FIKMsmjPRTR2vryaJRyg0TblF_jr-kWyeURwpbkPzsU6r3avEqM6dfTqhhASoXB4VmeZ2zw75pZgK4v8cfcd3J_tIpFRjcEY1TqPz5E3QrYQGfFSeBEEbjwqvj2X5_4VBvve7ABdrt3OCjid8E_837mLX-Fv5t3nk_nfnV0SY6XrFQQmoPClyqSyn44FTv_WFY7Af74SfeBrWDYSSiTuwphEmVTeT6U2R4Rs4wR8G0uHW2L53U-4UbkODd-_-JZYIahAohDAF-8TaguUwb4mOK497wsFOkgpmYz-np4MX3sTweSLmn6bAOy9Y91E3o4fuERzX9m9N_HBt64cv6k8JROKJqs6cx1Gb9EoYCRLCn2ihWi_crZh2PH5LACMCLWYgH0gAA&state=1527572151-IIZ0D&session_state=1faeaab9-0f00-45cb-a776-356463a54684

---

**Edit 4**

Today, I have done few more testing while upgrading project to .Net Core 2.1. I have notice that even though from interface it is confirming `Access your data anytime`, but when I use code to exchange access token, it doesn't contain refresh token.

The other thing I have notice is, when I pass scope as `User.Read`, and when I exchange access token, the scope came back as: `User.Read User.ReadBasic.All`. This is a bit of inconsistent, but not big issue.

[image]

Comment: Are you using AAD v1 endpoint with Microsoft graph?  For v1 endpoint, the scope isstatically configured in AAD App registration. So, if you have add `access user's data anytime` permission, you will also get the `offline_access` scope in your request.

Comment: What is the full URI you are requesting? Also, can you please add an example of the token you're getting back.

Comment: Just put those info inside Edit 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s not currently possible to  remove the offline_access scope from the initial consent screen when using the v2 endpoint with an AAD account.  When requesting tokens the offline_access scope is still explicitly requested though.

Comment: Are there any reason for this? It would be good if we could get some insights of what cause that.

Comment: Came across [this in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#openid-connect-scopes). From the "access_token" item: _While the offline_access scope is automatically requested by the server, your client must still request it in order to receive the refresh tokens._  However the question of WHY is not explained there.

Comment: This is a major issue for me. I have an app that needs to request *temporary* access to their Azure subscription to perform some actions on their behalf. It's important for the user to know that I won't do anything with their subscription at a later time. But even though I'm not requesting the `offline_access` scope, the consent message suggest that the app will maintain access, which is false...

Comment: The consent screen should only include consent for scopes that I requested. If I later request an additional scope, the consent screen should be displayed again with the new scope.

Answer (score 1):

**Cause:**

For v1 endpoint, the scope isstatically configured in AAD App registration. If you have add access user's data anytime permission, you will also get the offline_access scope in your request.

**Solution:**

If you don't want to let user have `offline_access` permission, you can unpick up the `Access user's data anytime` permission in Microsoft Graph delegated permissions.

[image]

**More about `offline_access`** :

`offline_access` is one of OpenID permissions. It's name is `offline_access` and it's Display String in v1 endpoint is Access user's data anytime.You can see more details about this permission in [this documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#openid-permissions).

Comment: Hi Jason, Is this answer helpful?

Comment: We are not use v1. Scope is defined in url. I also checked application we create. It doesn’t have offline access added.

Comment: So, Are you using v2 ednpoint?  Can you use fiddler to catch the reqeust when you access your app?

Comment: We can use fiddler to catch the request in development environment.

Comment: I have updated original question with screenshot on actual application we registered with MSFT on permissions.

Comment: Hi @JasonHe , How do you get access token with code? Did you refer to this :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-access-token

Answer (score 1):

This is an [issue](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/34738855-azure-ad-v2-0-oauth2-account-consent-page-always-l) which is in a **planned** state on Azure Active Directory suggestions and feedback site.
Admin's post (Oct 2, 2018) mentions a plan to fix this "within the next 3 months".

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: @GabrielBourgault https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/36f02e36-b625-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0789