# Azure OpenID connect app prompts for offline access

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I've registered an application/client on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ requesting only the openid scope, when I try to access that application via a link like

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token+token&client_id=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX&response_mode=form_post&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8765/test/response&scope=openid&state=123abc

One of the prompts on the authorization screen is "Access your data anytime" according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#offlineaccess that prompt should only be shown when requesting offline_access. 
What can I do to have it not prompt for "Access your data anytime"?

These are permissions requested in the app registration portal [image]

Comment: It seems you are using implicit flow. And that must not get a refresh token so "access your data anytime" should not present in consent. Can you try putting a space insted of a '+' in response type as this response_type=id_token token

Comment: So @KavinduDodanduwa, if I read you correct, I shouldn't be prompted for "access your data anytime"? I tried removing the plus but... it's really just a url encoded space so the difference is the same

Comment: Yes that's correct. According to docs you shouldn't get the consent page for this

Comment: Hi @vruum , Did add `Access your data anytime` delegated permissions in the AAD application permissions?

Comment: Hi @WayneYang-MSFT, no, I've added a screenshot of the requested permissions in the developer portal to my original post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure AD automatically added offline\_access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476455/azure-ad-automatically-added-offline-access)

Answer (score 0):

Please note that It’s not currently possible to  remove the offline_access scope from the initial consent screen when using the v2 endpoint with an AAD account. When requesting tokens the offline_access scope is still explicitly requested though.

Comment: are you saying that there's no way to not prompt for offline access with the v2 endpoint? That's got to be a bug, right? or is it documented somewhere?

Comment: To clarify: On the v2 authorize endpoint, when an application is first used by a user, we will collect consent for profile and offline_access even if those are not requested.  This is ONLY done on the authorize endpoint – you must still use the offline_access scope when requesting tokens from the /token endpoint in order to receive a refresh token.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, But, is there any reason for requesting this scope? or is it documented anywhere? We have customers asking why we're requesting excessive permissions, and it would be nice to have somewhere to point them to for clarification.

Comment: This is still an issue in 2020. Microsoft has not implemented OpenID correctly. We do not need offline_access, and it should not be added unnecessarily. @Mohit_Garg any timeline for fixing this?