# Azure AD provides refresh_token even I don't request and permissions does not have offline_access

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-page-application, openid-connect, azure-ad-graph-api, openid-client-js

I'm having really hard time to understand what's going on. My is my SPA keeps getting refresh_token even I don't request it and permissions on Azure has no offline_access.

What can I do to NOT get refresh_token?

### **My request URL (notice no offline_access is requested)**

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/........./oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=........&redirect_uri=........&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email%20User.Read&state=......&code_challenge=........&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=query
```

### **Permissions on Azure (no offline_access)**

[image]

### **Consent screen (ask user to give offline access permission)**

[image]

### **Result, I've refresh_token, not a good idea having refresh token on client.**

[image]

Comment: How did you request an access token?

Comment: I'm using vuex-oidc which at the end oidc-client-js is doing requests. The url I give above is the one oidc-client generates.

Comment: The request url you added is only used to obtain the authentication code.

Comment: If you add `offline_access` to the `scope` when requesting an access token, it will still return a refresh token.

Comment: So you're saying something happens during token request? I'll check that. But still why azure provides refresh token without offline_access in permission list?

Comment: I'm still having hard time to understand. Consent screen is before access token request. Why it's asking me for offline access?

Comment: see: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#OfflineAccess

Comment: Hi, any other concerns about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue when using azure ad v2.0 endpoint, related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476455/azure-ad-automatically-added-offline-access).

Also mentioned in [`offline_access`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#offline_access):

> This permission currently appears on all consent pages, even for flows that don't provide a refresh token (such as the implicit flow). This setup addresses scenarios where a client can begin within the implicit flow and then move to the code flow where a refresh token is expected.

But this does not affect that you don't want to get the refresh token, what you used is the [auth code flow v2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), just don't include the `offline_access` when [requesting the token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token), then the refresh token will not be returned.

Or if you really don't what the app let you consent this permission, just use the [auth code flow v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/v1-protocols-oauth-code), then if you don't include `offline_access` when you request the `code`, it will not let you consent the `offline_access` permission.

Comment: Seems https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js does not obey scope I defined (which has no `offline_access`) and still gets `refresh_token` while using `code flow` and yes no `refresh_token` with `implicit flow`. I tested `code flow` with a server side script where i intercept token request and add/remove `offline_access` and it works with `code flow`. So with `code flow` on SPA, am I stuck with a `refresh_token` since no idea how to intercept `oidc-client-js`?

Comment: @Ergec Actually you could use the implicit flow directly in SPA, it is a suitable scenario. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios#scenarios-and-supported-authentication-flows

Comment: @Ergec Because the goal of using auth code flow is that it returns Refresh tokens provide long-term access to resources on behalf of users without requiring interaction with those users, if you don't want refresh token, it is meaningless to use this flow.

Comment: I see. ~20K users and many possible unattended PCs, too much to think about. Anyway thanks a lot Joy.